# Generate heat map from a given data set

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following heat map, I want to start y values from 0 to 25. Now it is in the reverse direction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
a=[]
for i in range(25):
    b=[]
    for j in range(25):
        b.append(i*j)
    a.append(b)    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5.00))
plt.imshow(a,  interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 24, 2)                                              
minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 24, 1)                                               
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)                                                       
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
plt.xlabel(r'$\pmb{u} \  \longrightarrow$' )
plt.ylabel(r'$\pmb{v} \  \longrightarrow$')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('abc.eps', bbox_inches = 'tight',
    pad_inches = 0.2)
```

Comment: See the examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#images_contours_and_fields), then try making a plot with `imshow`, `pcolormesh` or `contourf`, and if you are still having trouble, then come back here with a specific problem you are having.

Comment: Unfortunately the aim of this question remains very vague. If I had to guess, I would say you want to plot a [`tripcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tripcolor_demo.html) plot.

Comment: Now I have mentioned the problem clearly. Please help me.

Comment: Solved. Need to include  origin='lower'

Comment: @user5020 can please you post your answer as an answer and not a comment? :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to include origin='lower'